# Replace multiple elements in string with str methods

Tags: python, string, replace

I am trying to write a function that takes a string of DNA and returns the compliment. I have been trying to solve this for a while now and looked through the Python documentation but couldn't work it out. I have written the docstring for the function so you can see what the answer should look like. I have seen a similar question asked on this forum but I could not understand the answers. I would be grateful if someone can explain this using only str formatting and loops / if statements, as I have not yet studied dictionaries/lists in detail.

I tried `str.replace` but could not get it to work for multiple elements, tried nested if statements and this didn't work either. I then tried writing 4 separate for loops, but to no avail.

```
def get_complementary_sequence(dna):

    """ (str) -> str

    Return the DNA sequence that is complementary 
    to the given DNA sequence.

    >>> get_complementary_sequence('AT')
    TA
    >>> get_complementary_sequence('GCTTAA')
    CGAATT

    """

    for char in dna:
        if char == A:
            dna = dna.replace('A', 'T')
        elif  char == T:
            dna = dna.replace('T', 'A')
        # ...and so on
```

Comment: what does this compliment do?

Comment: its supposed to find the compliment strand on a dna sequence. there are 4 nucleotides on a dna strand. so A on one strand compliments to T on the other strand. T with A, C with G and G with C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map each letter to another letter.

You probably need not create translation table with all possible combination.

```
>>> M = {'A':'T', 'T':'A', 'C':'G', 'G':'C'}
>>> STR = 'CGAATT'
>>> S = "".join([M.get(c,c) for c in STR])
>>> S
'GCTTAA'
```

How this works:

```
# this returns a list of char according to your dict M
>>> L = [M.get(c,c) for c in STR]  
>>> L
['G', 'C', 'T', 'T', 'A', 'A']
```

The method join() returns a string in which the string elements of sequence have been joined by str separator.

```
>>> str = "-"
>>> L = ['a','b','c']
>>> str.join(L)
'a-b-c'
```

Comment: thank you this works, just for my learning though why do you have "".join in line 3?

Comment: Using `str.translate()` is simpler and would be much faster at doing the replacements -- the creation of translation tables is trivial with `string.maketrans()` (or `str.maketrans()` in Python 3).

Comment: Since there are 4 nucleotides, one would need to pass two 4 letter strings to `string.maketrans()` to create a translation table that could be used to complement any sequence -- see [@nneonneo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27659678/355230).

Answer (score 5):

For a problem like this, you can use [`string.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) ([`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) in Python 3) combined with [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
import string
table = string.maketrans('CGAT', 'GCTA')
print 'GCTTAA'.translate(table)
# outputs CGAATT
```

Comment: will this work on any dna strand, say something much longer with a random sequence?

Comment: @DataScienceAcademy: Yes. This just translates each character according to the translation table. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for more details.